# R: How to calculate rates between observations by group?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say we have a dataframe like the following one:

```
cohort month customers
Jan    01    523
Jan    02    332
Jan    03    221
Jan    04    190
Feb    02    489
Feb    03    310
Feb    04    205
Mar    03    372
Mar    04    192
Apr    04    340
```

My aim is to create a brand new column storing the retention rate for each cohort. To do this, I'd need to calculate how many customers do remain in the last month (04) related to the total ones joining each cohort for the first time.

I'm striving with `dplyr` to achieve two tables that would look like the ones below:

One calculating the current retention rate for each cohort:

```
cohort  rr
Jan     0.36
Feb     0.42
Mar     0.52
```

And, perhaps the most important one, another that could give me the RR evolution in a monthly basis like the one below:

```
cohort month customers period rr
Jan    01    523       0     1
Jan    02    332       1     0.63
Jan    03    221       2     0.42
Jan    04    190       3     0.36
Feb    02    489       0     1
Feb    03    310       1     0.63
Feb    04    205       2     0.42
Mar    03    372       0     1
Mar    04    192       1     0.52
Apr    04    340       0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(cohort) %>%
 mutate(period = 1:n() - 1,
        rr = customers/first(customers))

  cohort month customers period    rr
   <chr>  <int>     <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Jan        1       523      0 1    
 2 Jan        2       332      1 0.635
 3 Jan        3       221      2 0.423
 4 Jan        4       190      3 0.363
 5 Feb        2       489      0 1    
 6 Feb        3       310      1 0.634
 7 Feb        4       205      2 0.419
 8 Mar        3       372      0 1    
 9 Mar        4       192      1 0.516
10 Apr        4       340      0 1
```

For the second table:

```
df %>%
 group_by(cohort) %>%
 summarise(rr = last(customers)/first(customers))

  cohort    rr
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 Apr    1    
2 Feb    0.419
3 Jan    0.363
4 Mar    0.516
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df %>% group_by(cohort) %>% summarise(rr = sum(customers[n()])/customers[1])
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  cohort    rr
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 Apr    1    
2 Feb    0.419
3 Jan    0.363
4 Mar    0.516
```

For second one, another take:

```
df %>% group_by(cohort) %>% mutate(period = 0:(n()-1), rr = customers/customers[1])
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   cohort [4]
   cohort month customers period    rr
   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
 1 Jan    01          523      0 1    
 2 Jan    02          332      1 0.635
 3 Jan    03          221      2 0.423
 4 Jan    04          190      3 0.363
 5 Feb    02          489      0 1    
 6 Feb    03          310      1 0.634
 7 Feb    04          205      2 0.419
 8 Mar    03          372      0 1    
 9 Mar    04          192      1 0.516
10 Apr    04          340      0 1
```